# SPF questions - how to set up

Tags: email, spam, spf

I would like to set up SPF for my domain example.com on my own server but I don't really understand how to do this, so here are my questions:

1) What does my SPF record(s) have to look like if I would like to allow my server IP x.x.x.x sending mail using mail@example.com (or better *@example.com)?

2) Where do I have to add the SPF record? To my DNS records? How do I store it there???

3) I would also like to send Mails from my laptop using myname@example.com, and I'm using my server IP x.x.x.x as SMTP server, I guess that's not a problem with the SPF record then?

Hope it doesn't sound too stupid, but I find this SPF thing a bit confusing ;)

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Not yet, as this is a production site, I don't want to break anything unless I know what I'm doing :/

Comment: In my DNS config I can add an SPF rule, I can enter 2 fields  ("host" and "rule")...

Answer (score 1):

Use a SPF generation wizard, like this one: http://spfwizard.com/

> 1) What does my SPF record(s) have to look like if I would like to
>   allow my server IP x.x.x.x sending mail using mail@example.com (or
>   better *@example.com)?

In BIND record format, it could be something like:

```
example.com. IN TXT "v=spf1 mx ip4:x.x.x.x ~all"
```

Basically, it allows to send emails from:

- all the MX records for example.com
- the ip x.x.x.x

the other cases are qualified as [softfail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework#Qualifiers).

> 2) Where do I have to add the SPF record? To my DNS records? How do I
>   store it there???

You must be allowed to edit the DNS records for the domain example.com. Most likely it's a service provided by your registrar. You say you have 2 fields: you should add example.com (your domain) in the **host** field, and the "v=spf1.." string (withoud quotes) in the **rule** field.

> 3) I would also like to send Mails from my laptop using
>   myname@example.com, and I'm using my server IP x.x.x.x as SMTP server,
>   I guess that's not a problem with the SPF record then?

Well said, you got the point.